# How can Skyler buy a $800k car wash

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, breaking-bad

I don't get how an unemployed teacher can buy a car wash?

I know it's just a plot, but do the writers ever refer to loaning the amount or justify buying Bogdan's car wash?

Any money laundering experts here?

Comment: I've edited the question to focus on the main point of your original post. if you have *additional* questions, please ask hthem separately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, they claim that Walt won the money gambling and Saul arranges for casinos to provide fake confirmation.

This is covered in the Season 3, Episode 11 *Abiquiu* where the conversation goes something like..

> So to begin with, what are we saying is the source of this money?
>
> That's simple. **Walt here, actually came up with a great story about gambling winnings.**
>
> Blackjack, right? Some card-counting system?
>
> Well, actually that was Skyler's idea.
>
> Well, you grow more gorgeous by the minute. There you have it. I'll generate false Currency Transaction Reports out the wazoo as well as the necessary W-2Gs. **I know a couple casino managers who will jump at the chance to report false losses.**

This actually becomes a plot point later on when the IRS claim $600k+ as tax on the winnings (which, of course, Walt is reluctant to pay).

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed that. I also missed out on the IRS claim of '$600k+" - what episode are you referring to there?