# With the Spa laundering money idea, how would Jesse explain the Spa buying in first place?

Tags: realism, breaking-bad

In the episode *Kafkaesque* (S03E09), Saul advises Jesse to buy the spa/salon to help him launder money.

The idea can probably work, but Jesse will still have to explain how he bought a spa that cost a few hundred thousand dollars, just after buying a $400k house.

Wouldn't the IRS find this situation suspicious, especially if Jesse's legit job cover is just a laundromat job?

Comment: Related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93532/how-can-skyler-buy-a-800k-car-wash

Comment: One might wonder how buying a $400k house in cash wouldn't trigger those same flags

Comment: @KaiQing IANA but it seems normal in US to walk around with bags of cash and buy cars, houses...

Comment: Sadly, i think this is simply expected to be explained away by Saul doing some legal magic to make it all look legitimate.

Answer (score 3):

Jesse "purchased" his house through Saul, who very likely used a shell company to do so. Saul is known to use tactics such as this for personal use in his many schemes for example he requests payments to a company called Ice Station Zebra as to not directly associate himself with them. So while Jesse is living in that house it is unlikely he used his own name on the title. In the case of the Spa that tactic may have been used again, or he very well may have been able to get a small business loan for the down payment, which for most people is possible and avoids suspicion.